# SQL Error [1525] [HY000]: Incorrect DATETIME value: ''

Tags: mysql

I get the error `SQL Error [1525] [HY000]: Incorrect DATETIME value: ''` when running following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where date_time_column >=''
```

The query was working for the past few months and it started giving the above error since yesterday.

My MySQL version is `8.0.17`.

I tried running the code via older versions of my code and still get the same error.
Even trying it in MySQL Workbench gives the same error.

What Database config changes would have caused this?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to find all records where there is any value at all in the specific columns. Have you considered WHERE date_time_column IS NOT NULL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's seems not related to database changes itself, but something changed in version `8.0.16` regarding comparison on `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` types against `strings`. The behavior is documented already in `8.0.16` change log as following:

> When comparing `DATE` values with constant strings, MySQL first tries to
>   convert the string to a `DATE` and then to perform the comparison. When
>   the conversion failed, MySQL executed the comparison treating the `DATE`
>   as a string, which could lead to unpredictable behavior. Now in such
>   cases, if the conversion of the string to a `DATE` fails, the comparison
>   fails with `ER_WRONG_VALUE`. (Bug #29025656)

Also, this is reported as a [bug here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95466).

PD: Your query works on my old 5.7 MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that a TRIGGER would try to update that same field after every update to a row.

The trigger would not use the correct format when making a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue with mysql 8.0. After I exec my sql insert in Mysql command it looks like below:

```
Query: insert into t_user(user_id, eff_dateFrom, eff_dateTo, status...
Error Code: 1525
Incorrect DATETIME value: ''
```

I spend few hours to find out the error, end up realized my Trigger cause the problem. My trigger didnt do datetime format correctly. When I exec the command actually it will trigger the trigger and the script run the wrong datetime format in trigger and cause the error.

Thanks for the clues.